# Access task arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, task

I have a task adapter

```
public static ServiceReturnObject<T> CheckServiceResult<T>(Task<T> functionTask)
{
    ServiceReturnObject<T> serviceReturnObject = new ServiceReturnObject<T>();
    var result = functionTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
...
}
```

which i can call with

```
CheckServiceResult(GetSomaAlgorithmResultAsync(header, AlgoNo));
```

where `GetSomaAlgorithmResultAsync` is a function and header and `AlgoNo` are parameters I pass.

This works. No problem.

`functionTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` works fine with parameters but I cant get the parameters myself. This is here just as a proof of concept that I can run the funcTask with parameters correctly. Dont stay on that.

How can I access parameters (header or AlgoNo) from within `CheckServiceResult`?

Comment: `This works. No problem.` actually, that's a very serious bug that leads to wasted threads and CPU at best, deadlocks and even cascading crashes at worst. `.GetResult();` blocks the calling thread while waiting for the asynchronous operation to complete, eating up a CPU core. That's almost *never* a good idea, unless the task had already completed. `serviceReturnObject` is never used.

Comment: CheckServiceResult takes a Task not a Function. And as far as i know the Task does not have the info about what Function might have created it.

Comment: The reason this can cause cascading server crashes is that task are *not* meant to be blocked. In general, blocking is supposed to be short lived. To avoid evicting a thread from the CPU and having to reschedule it, .NET starts each blocking operation by spinwaiting, which uses 100% of a core. Only once the spinwait ends will .NET allow the thread to be evicted. If a moderately busy application blocks like this, all available CPU cores will end up doing nothing but heating the CPU.

Comment: At some point IIS, Kubernetes or whatever monitors the server will recycle the application and redirect the traffic to another server in the farm ... which could proceed to livelock itself

Comment: Thank you, the site has been working for three years now, and im not the developer, i just want to cache the result based on the parameters. ServiceReturnObject is used down below. I wonder how functionTask can run with passed parameters but i cant see them.

Answer (score 1):

> This works. No problem.

Until there are. You should not block on async code. There are numerous problem which can happen - deadlocks, resource wasting, etc.

> How can I access parameters from within CheckServiceResult?

You can't (at least in relatively easy way). There are two approaches which require signature and logic changes (switching to factory approach):

1. Use [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/), so you change from `Task<T> functionTask` parameter to `Expression<Func<Task<T>>>` and then process the expression tree to get invocation parameters:

```
public static ServiceReturnObject<T> CheckServiceResult<T>(Expression<Func<Task<T>>> expr)
{
   var task = expression.Compile()(); // compile and start task
   // process expression
   
}
```

Processing the expression can be quite cumbersome (you will need to process closures) and there is performance hit involved but you will be able to keep the signature.

2. Create a lot of `CheckServiceResult` overloads for different number of parameters (maybe using source generators):

```
public static ServiceReturnObject<TResult> CheckServiceResult<T, TResult>(Func<T, Task<TResult>> expr, T p)
{
   var task = expr()(p);
   
}
public static ServiceReturnObject<TResult> CheckServiceResult<T, T1, TResult>(Func<T, T1, Task<TResult>> expr, T p, T1 p1)
...
```

Which makes the method simpler and has less performance impact, but usage changes to: `CheckServiceResult(GetSomaAlgorithmResultAsync, header, AlgoNo)` (leveraging method group syntax).